# SLF4J Custom Binding Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, slf4j

We spent a lot of time developing our own custom logging system (right or wrong, thats what the higher-ups decided on!) and I have been asked to write a custom SLF4J binding (API implementation) so that many of our SLF4J-utilizing components (such as Apache Camel) will start logging to our new homegrown system.

I have followed the instructions on SLF4J's site to a "T", creating:

- A `StaticLoggerBinder` that SLF4J uses at runtime to bind to `Loggers` and `LoggerFactory` classes
- A logger adaptor that will be used to "forward" `org.slf4j.Logger` calls on to
- A logger factory (used by the static logger binder)

Everything compiles great. I jar it up and add it to the `lib` directory of a test project, along with `slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar` (the version they want me to use).  I added both JARs to the build path in Eclipse.

I create a new Run Configuration for the test project, and under the Run Configuration's `Classpath` tabbed pane I see it has `User Entries >> TestBinding >> Slf4jBinding.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar`.

So, it seems like both JARs are inside the Run Configuration's classpath.

Upon running a driver inside the project that looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestDriver.class);
    logger.error("Test");
}
```

I get the following runtime errors:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Going to that referenced site, it seems that SLF4J cannot find my `StaticLoggerBinder` on the classpath, which is inside the `Slf4jBinding.jar`, although not at the root level of the JAR.

I looked at SLF4J's `LoggerFactory.java` source file and found the code that throws this kind of error:

```
private final static void bind() {
    try {
        // the next line does the binding
        StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton();
        INITIALIZATION_STATE = SUCCESSFUL_INITILIZATION;
        emitSubstituteLoggerWarning();
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ncde) {
        String msg = ncde.getMessage();
        if (messageContainsOrgSlf4jImplStaticLoggerBinder(msg)) {
            INITIALIZATION_STATE = NOP_FALLBACK_INITILIZATION;
            Util
            .report("Failed to load class \"org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder\".");
            Util.report("Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation");
            Util.report("See " + NO_STATICLOGGERBINDER_URL
            + " for further details.");
        } // ...
```

Clearly, the call at the top of the `try` block (`StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()`) is throwing the `NoClassDefFoundError`. I just don't understand why.

I elected not to paste my code here because I think this is just a classpath issue. Whether or not my code correctly adheres to SLF4J's binding policies remains unknown until I can get passed this issue.

Is there an additional step I need to take inside Eclipse to configure the classpath? Could my `Slf4jBinding.jar` need `StaticLoggerBinder` inside its root for some reason?  I am out of ideas here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your StaticLoggerBinder is org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder?

Comment: `although not at the root level of the JAR`, what does this mean? In order to be found your class must be at `/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class` inside the jar, if it is in a sub-folder it won't be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of starting completely from scratch then just adapt e.g. slf4j-simple.jar to your needs.  All the binding code is there, you just need to adapt the code doing the actual logging.

Answer (score 7):

Your jar needs a custom implementation of  `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` and that implementation's fully qualified class name must be exactly `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`. The static binding works having the SLF4J API compiled against a stub version of `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` and then at runtime a classloader will load a real version from an SLF4J binding . Each binding of SLF4J has a different version of a the class `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` suitable for that particular binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an org.slf4j.impl package in your project and implement a class named StaticLoggerBinder in that package, just like explained on http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com/2011/12/custom-slf4j-logger-adapter.html (I just did that and it works just fine for me).

Note that you do not need to build a jar file for that, you just need to have a org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class accessible in your classpath (it can be in a jar but that is not mandatory).